# how to use a `switch` statement in Go

Tags: go, switch-statement, conditional-statements

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var age int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &age)

    // Code your switch or if...else-if statement here.
    
    switch age {
    case 1:
        age <= 14
        fmt.Println("Toy Story 4")
    case 2:
        age <= 18
        fmt.Println("The Matrix")
    case 3:
        age <= 25
        fmt.Println("John Wick")
    case 4:
        age <= 35
        fmt.Println("Constantine")
    case 5:
        age > 35
        fmt.Println("Speed")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Error: Unknown age")
    }
}
```

I get a yellow marker in the IDE for the `scanf`, flagging an unhandled error. Also, all the cases have the first line flagged red, preventing to compile. The error I get is `age <= 14 is evaluated, but not used`. The same is true for all statements. I have searched the web and looked at examples, and from what I can see, the code is, as the materials and examples state. Here is a screenshot from Go Land (JetBrains):

Does anybody have an idea? Also, if you answer, please keep in mind, that this is a lesson from a Go course and I have to use scanf. I could change the switch to an else if, which is likely going to fix the issue, but I am kind of curious, about why this is happening and how I can fix it. :)

Comment: Welcome to Go!  Please make sure you've taken the tour (https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started).

Comment: You probably want to review [Switch Statements](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/9) (or in [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#switch)), as well as basic syntax. The comparisons need to be in the case expressions.

Comment: While we are at it, [please do not post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052). All the relevant bits of text you wanted to show us could have well be copied as text and pasted into the question's text.

Comment: Yeah, we hate text as screenshots here at SO.  Your question was clear and complete without them.  Instead of bringing editor screenshots into it, you might use the Go Playrgound in the future to share behavior (https://go.dev/play/) but like I said this question was fine as written, without screenshots

Comment: Thanks for all those comments! I am sorry about the screenshots and will edit them out. As for the issue: I am a tester for JetBrains Academy and this is a kinda new topic. Since I had my eye on Go for some time, I agreed to test it and then go from there. The issue is with their theory. Their code instructions are wrong. So that's why I couldn't figure it out. :) Thanks gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`age <= 14` is not a valid Go expression, though it could be used as part of one.  Go is very particular about all values being consumed.

This isn't the correct way to write a `case` with `<=` operators.

```
    switch age {
    case 1:
        age <= 14
        fmt.Println("Toy Story 4")
    ...
    }
```

That case matches if the value of `age` is `1`.  You want to use a switch style like this:

```
switch {
case age <= 14:
   fmt.Println("Toy Story 4")
case age <= 18:
   ...
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work. I am testing this paid Go course for JetBrains Academy. I had my eye on Go for some time now, so it was a good opportunity. The issue is with their theory, which was causing me trouble. I can't post it here as a comment, it looks weird, but it basically is what I did. It asks for switch variable case: and then below the code to be run.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Daniel wrote — basically the switch statement (unless it's a type switch but let's not digress) has two forms:

```golang
switch { // note the absense of any expression here
  case bool_expr_1:
    ...
  case bool_expr_2:
    ...
```

and

```golang
switch any_expr {
  case value_to_match_1:
    ...
  case value_to_match_2:
    ...
```

In the first form, expressions in each `case` branch are evaluated top-to-bottom, and the first which evaluates to `true`, "wins"—that is, the code in that branch is executed.
In the second form, the expression is evaluated to produce a value which is then compared exactly with the value in each case branch.

You have tried to sort-of combine both forms, which won't work.
You might have thought that those numbers in the case branches is the order of how the branches should be checked but no, that's not it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that detailed explanation. I had a brain fart with the numbers in the case, actually. It did not make sense because the user is not supposed to enter a single number but an age, which is then to be checked. But even this fact left aside, the theory of the class was wrong in, that in this case the switch statement should not have had an expression.  It needs to be amended and changed to deal with both cases and make clear when to use which one.  I also guess that in my brain, I was having Java in mind somewhat. :)